# Running a batch file from java

Tags: java, windows, batch-file

I just downloaded [MCP](http://mcp.ocean-labs.de/index.php/MCP_Releases) to see how things work behind the scenes in Minecraft.

Inside MCP there are a bunch of batch files that you use to do things like: decompile, recompile, startclient, etc.

What I would like to be able to do is run these batch files from a basic java gui.

I'm good with the gui part but I havent got a clue how to run those batch files.

Here is an example of one of the batch files:

**The file is at:**

C:\MCP\startclient.bat

**startclient contains the following:**

```
@echo off

:try_python
set PYTHON=python
%PYTHON% --version >NUL 2>NUL
if errorlevel 1 goto try_python_mcp
goto foundit

:try_python_mcp
set PYTHON=runtime\bin\python\python_mcp
%PYTHON% --version >NUL 2>NUL
if errorlevel 1 (
    echo Unable to locate python.
    pause
    exit /b
)

:foundit
%PYTHON% runtime\startclient.py conf\mcp.cfg
pause
```

Can it be done?

Comment: I am surprised they do not offer an x-plat `build.xml` or similar.  What decade(/millennium) are they developing in?

Answer (score 4):

You can easily run a batch file from java using Runtime:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start " + yourbatchFileName);
```

you can also grab I/O of the process, using `p.getOutputStream()`, `p.getInputStream()` etc.

See more about the Process class [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html).

And I suggest you take a look at [this article](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html) as well.

Comment: But this would be outside JVM.

Comment: Batch files are not intended for java, but for (usually) windows cmd, this is the only way I know about running those from java with maximum control.

Comment: Good call on adding the link to the Java World 'gotchas' article.  Anybody that attempts to use a `Process` needs to read that, sooner or later.

Comment: So I plugged in: Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start C:\\MCP\\recompile.bat");

Comment: But when it pops up it complains: Unable to locate python. Then it exits to the java project folder, not the MCP folder? Might be noobish but, do I need to start cmd in the MCP folder for it to work?

Comment: It's hard for me to tell you how to set up the paths, but at least we know it is called. use `echo %CD%`to see what's your current directory.

Comment: So I dropped the echo %CD% into the batch file to get the folder.

Comment: I then ran the batch from java, and a double click. They come up with different folders. So I guess my next question should be: "how do I get the java to start in cmd in the correct folder?"

Comment: WAHAHA :) Sorted. You the man MByD. All I did was take the jar file for my gui and drop it in the folder. Couldn't have done it without you friend :)

Comment: @Piyush You cannot run a batch file inside the JVM. JVM can run only Java and other languages that are built to run inside it. A batch file is a set of commands issued to the operating system. Those instructions cannot run inside a JVM.